# Switching tabs breaks background images when using the CSS styling perspective

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

Any ideas why?

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Load the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhellman1/4fTeA/1/
2. In the result box, scroll down a half way
3. Switch to another tab
4. Then go back to the fiddle, notice the background image broke, it's gone, and all you now see it the background color

The background-image should persist when tabbing through chrome. Instead, switching to another Chrome tab breaks the background-image

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of all of this code fixes it for me:

```
#number .flipper {
    perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

Not even sure what that does exactly.